# How to display Magento Custom Options Individually

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

My Magento site has a product which has a few Custom Options, one text, one file upload and four drop down lists.

The design of the site dictates that I need to show these options throughout the product view page and not all in one group.

Is there a function that I can call to return the HTML of a single Custom Option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways to do this that are tantamount to cheating.

Your shop requires javascript to operate and there is a lot you can do with Prototype before the page renders, by using the on dom:loaded event. You can attach your custom options to wherever you want in the DOM, or you can hide them and put something else where you want it on the page that updates the form element. You may want to do this if you have to capture a colour name but don't want to put oodles of colours on every product - a textbox can go on the product and your control can write to it.

The benefit of some $$('cheating') is that you don't have to go too deep into Magento code for what is a 'design consideration'.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up cheating big time. I rendered the page that Magento gave me, took the source code and built a hard coded version of the page. Not a pleasant experience and I have accrued a large amount of technical debt in the process. Im not looking forward to the next set of amends in that page!

Comment: I have a custom option for cart weight display at Ajax cart in Magento 1.9.2.3. How to give condition to display this custom option for only selected IP address, My code: https://justpaste.it/1jfgn how can I add ip address filter.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand correctly about group. If you mean category then ;

create a new attribute set which this attribute set should contain attributes that you want to show. After that, when you create a product, select this attribute set instead of default. So that, only this attributes will be available in the specified products.

Try the following code snippets ( don't forget to change "attribute_code")

Let say, you want to show Multi Select list in your product page, in that case :

```
$selectArray = $this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE');  
$endOfArray = end($selectArray);

echo "<ul class='set-some-class'>";
foreach($selectArray as $selectionItem) {  
  echo "<li> . $selectionItem";
  if($selectionItem != $endOfArray) {  
    echo "</li>\n";
  } else {
    echo "</ul>";
  }
}
```

For page other than product view page, in that case:

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE');  
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);  
$lastOption = end($options);  

echo "<ul class='set-some-class'";
foreach($options as $option) {  
  echo $option['label'];  
  if($option != $lastOption) {  
    echo "<li>\n";
  } else {  
    echo "</ul>";
  }
}
```

Comment: When the Custom Options for a product are returned they are grouped together, they are all inside one <dl> block. The design of the site I am building needs the custom options to be spread throughout the page. My question is; can I call custom options individually so that they can be rendered individually rather than all at once in one block/group in the product page.

Comment: @OğuzÇelikdemir I have a custom option for cart weight display at Ajax cart in Magento 1.9.2.3. How to give condition to display this custom option for only selected IP address, My code : https://justpaste.it/1jfgn how can i add ip address filter.